# What happened to Voldemort in the end of "Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 2"?

Tags: harry-potter, movie, voldemort

At the end of the movie ***Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Part 2***:

> Voldemort and Harry had their final face off. When Harry won, Voldemort disintegrated.

Why did this happen?

Note that I'm looking for answers consistent with the movies. Information from the books that explain what happened while remaining consistent with the movies is acceptable.

Comment: No. Voldemort died because all his horcruxes were gone and he had Avada Kedavra cast on him.

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ: Yes, all the horcruxes are gone. However, in the movie (which I specified in the q), no spells are cast in the final face off, it's a duel.

Comment: [Real Men Have Dueling Scars](http://www.missedinhistory.com/blogs/real-men-have-dueling-scars.htm)

Comment: They get ground up to make Bertie Bott's Every Flavour Beans™

Comment: In general, use the [tag:movie] tag to specify that you aren't looking for the book version. It may also help to add a line saying that you are aware of the books version of the event, bit are seeking for a movie explanation.

Comment: @GreenMatt - you keep using that word. I don't think it means what you think it means. "Duel" is just a magical fight using spells. What you SEEM to be asking about is "something where 2 wands shoot lazer beams at each other and connect and hold that" - which is still a spell, they just basically did a cool visual for a movie.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To yeah he keeps saying that.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To: It seems you're right, I misunderstood what the term "duel" meant in the movies. I went back and watched the duel scene in GoF, and spells were cast, which I didn't remember; that said, I don't remember anything but the "lazer beams" (i.e. no audible spells) in the movie duels, thus my thinking. I flagged the question hoping to have it deleted (since the system would not let me delete it), but that was rejected, so I'll re-phrase it.

Answer (score 17):

The old answer based on the books can be found further down. But as GreenMat insists on an answer from the movies I have to say: There is NO logical explanation in the movies for what happens to Voldemort. Neither does the disintegration happen in any other instance of a duel nor is there any spell in the movies that can cause something like this.

The closest thing to the disintegration we get is the effect on Quirrell when touching Harry in the first movie, where something very similar happens.

So a movie- explanation MIGHT be, that it is the protection from his mother that lets the bad guys disintegrate. But still this is inconsistent with the fourth movie, where Voldemort -after getting his new body- can touch Harry without disintegrating.

As you can see in 4th, 5th 6th and 7th movie: whenever Voldemort tries to kill Harry he uses the unforgivable curse number one *Avada Kedavra*.

It always looks the same (green flash) as the spell in the last duel. And Harry always uses *Expelliarmus*, the red beam, especially in the duel in the fourth movie at the graveyard.

We also see in the movies that Voldemort is able to do magic without actually saying the words (e.g. when he forces Harry to bow by just pointing his wand at him.

These two facts let us assume, that it was *Avada Kedavra* again -this time unspoken- in the last duel.

WHY the bounced back spell lets Voldemort disintegrate while normally it "just kills" is not explained but could be made to refer to Quirrell in the first movie.

**Answer from the book:**

The movies are quite inaccurate in a lot of ways, and this is one of them.

In the books there is no difference between casting a spell and duelling. In the 6th book we learn, that experienced wizards can cast spells by just "thinking" them without speaking them out loud. They learn the "unspoken spells" at school.

It is said in the books that casting a spell without saying it loud gives you an advantage especially in duels, as your opponent cannot prepare for the spell as he doesn't hear it.

In the final duel in the book none of the two uses an unspoken spell: Harry casts his favorite spell "Expelliarmus" while Voldemort uses -guess- "Avada Kedavra". As Harry wins Voldemort's spell bounces back to him and kills him (this is NOT normal in a duel but due to the fact of the Elder Wand's true allegiance).

And no, he does NOT disintegrate, this is made for the effect of it only in the movie.

To answer your question: the loser just experiences the spell the winner cast. Of course a Death Eater might kill the loser with another spell after winning, but that is not part of the duel.

Comment: +1 just for the first line ... and the rest of the answer, of course ;-) It's [not always expressed so politely.](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22the+films+are+nonsense%22)

Comment: Responding by saying the movies are "inaccurate" and then providing an explanation from the books isn't an answer to a question that is specifically about the movies. An answer using information from the books could be acceptable if it explains something that happened in the movies without an explanation and didn't contradict what happened in the movies. However, that isn't what was done here.

Comment: @GreenMatt: I totally **disagree**. The answer has explained it all. If you asked the question just to know why did this happen in the movies, then the answer is specifically obvious, beacuse most of the movies are nonsense. This site is used for **asking canon information** which Torsten Link explained very well. We used books here for *canon answering*.

Comment: @BookStriker - If you feel that question is off-topic you can downvote or flag it. (When you get enough rep you can vote to close it.) However, this answer doesn't answer the question that was asked.

Comment: @ibid: yes. the answer doesn't answer the question.(because of the huge difference between movies and books) But it proves canon of 'what' really happened and 'why' to clarify false synopsis that materialized in the movies.

Comment: I don't think flagging will help because I don't think it was off-topic at any cause, since the movie tag was included recently.

Comment: @BookStriker: The question specifically asked about the movie from the beginning.

Comment: @GreenMatt: you asked 2 different questions. What happens to someone who loses a duel and why did voldemort disintegrate. I believe that two has difference.

Comment: @BookStriker: If you want to critique the q, please do so in response to it, not an answer. To address your complaint, I'm trying to understand - within the context of the movie - why Voldemort disintegrated. Was that an effect of losing the duel, or something else? (And I know that you and Torsten have already stated that the book is different and the movie makes no sense, so no need to repeat yourself.)

Comment: @GreenMatt: I answered it very well. If you think this answer is criticizing your question, take a look with this link Randal'Thor has provided.http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22the+films+are+nonsense%22 :)

Comment: @TorstenLink you practically have a good point here! I think it is reasonable that this is the answer since there is no any canonical evidence that proves Voldemort disintegrated for a reason.

Comment: I think Reddit is where I read this thought that makes perfect sense and I'm surprised Rowling agreed to the disintegration (same for Bellatrix and also Nagini). All his life Tom was terrified of death; he wanted to conquer death. The fact then he disintegrates, disappearing it seems, when that's what happened to him when AK backfired on Harry the first time and also I want to say when he left Quirrel: not only does it make it seem like he might return it also shows he didn't die as a regular human being: instead of showing that his efforts were in vain he dies magnificently. Rather a shame.

Answer (score 5):

**The body he re-built was flawed**

The spell used to bring him back:

> Bone of the father, unknowingly given, you will renew your son! Flesh of the servant, willingly sacrificed, you will revive your master. Blood of the enemy, forcibly taken, you will resurrect your foe.

While he rebuilt body with the spell, his *soul* was already broken, several times.

You could interpret the soul as the glue that holds a persons body together, and that once Harry and co destroyed the horcruxes, Voldemorts's body couldn't hold itself together, and so he disintegrates.

Voldemort had already cast one major killing curse (in the forest), which knocked him off his feet. Trying another + no more horcruxes was too much for him.

Comment: Letting you know the question has be re-worked, in case you want to re-word your answer.

Comment: Thanks for an answer that works within the context.

Comment: While this is perfectly fine as an explanation, do you have anything in canon to back this up?

Comment: @Adamant I will take a look and put in what I can find

Comment: If splitting one's soul would be a solid process, then there wouldn't be possible unstable side effects. In addition it's not like Voldermort looked very human, another indication of being something other or incomplete. I think this answer makes a great deal of sense.

Answer (score 3):

### That scene in the movie makes no sense. It is just an added features and effects the movie, which didn't happen in the book.

Similar to what Torsten Link has answered above which was explained very well: the synopsis that happened in that part of the 8th movie is just a false information, Voldemort just died, but it is the book which where these movies came from, and the book is considered canon since it has every info you need to know and this was the official scenario of J.K's harry potter series.

In the book, they didn't fly in black smoke, which was performed by Voldemort. And before the last duel of Harry and Voldemort started, they still managed to exchange discussions including the true loyalty of Snape and the Elder Wand.

But this is just a recap of what I have read in the book 7. But then, you asked what happens to someone who loses a duel in the movie. And you cited an example of why did Voldemort disintegrate in the 8th movie. In the book, Voldemort was killed by his own spell.

As for what happens to someone who loses a duel, they lost, or **sometimes**   die *if and only* AK spell hit him/her or something dangerous spell hit him/her. (**NOTE:** **I am not generalizing each and every scenarios that when someone was hit by a dangerous spell it kills him/her**) As for what is the reason why did that happen in the movie, because that scene in the movie makes no sense at all.

Comment: 5 paragraphs to say "... that scene in the movie makes no sense at all."? Which doesn't answer the question anyway

Comment: @GreenMatt: I explained my answer because you think that spellcasting with incantation with a mix of fight and dueling are not the same, the commenters above also reminded you that you keep insisting that they are different so I explained it for you. You asked why did this happen in the movie, because it makes no sense. Doesn't that answer your question if you don't favor the answer of Torsten Link? Maybe you want to take a look at this. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22the+films+are+nonsense%22

Comment: **The reason why Voldemort disintegrated is because that is just another special effects for the movie**. You keep insisting that it is because he lost the duel, when in reality, the *books are where they get every single information* in the movie.

Comment: Letting you know the question has be re-worked, in case you want to re-word your answer.

Comment: @GreenMatt yes it's better for the question to be reworked about the duels. It's not that kind of bad though. I'm just saying movies influenced so much HP lovers with wrong information, which means it removes the real canon and exchanges it to a fake one. I was once also just a movie lover until I realized they changed so many plots and super lack of information. That's why I answered it *the movie makes no sense*, I don't really mean any offense. But I will still stay firm to my answer. I'll just remove the spell part as you mentioned it was edited recently.

Comment: @GreenMatt You ask why Voldemort disintegrates; “there is no adequate explanation for why Voldemort disintegrates” **is** an answer to the question. It also happens to be the only correct answer to the question. Just like there's nothing to explain why Molly’s curse doesn't kill Bellatrix so much as shatter her like a pane of glass.

Comment: @BlackWood the asker detailed *why did Voldemort disintegrate* not *what happened in the 8th movie*. edited it for clarifying the asker's question.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Indeed it could be, and you're welcome to make such an answer if you want (or upvote Torsten's answer, which now essentially says the same thing). However, saying "That's not what really happened. In the books blah blah blah happened" is *NOT* answering the question I asked.

Comment: @GreenMatt since you asked why did this happen, the reason I said it makes no sense because *the movie is not a very canonized information rather than the books which are officially written by J.K. Rowling. If you will just keep on insisting this part of the movie happened for a reason, then no doubt no answer will testify any proof of why did this happen in a not canonized movie.

Comment: @Invoker There is however the possible out of universe reason that a body that crumbles to dust after being hit by a spell from the good guys (Molly with Bella and Voldy with, well, his own rebounded one) does not leave behind the visual image of a *hero* character killing. It's a movie, and even if filmed in Britain was still produced by Warner, so American censorship laws apply - and maybe to get a specfic rating you can't have the good guys leaving bodies behind... so to have them desintegrate is a nice way around that...

Answer (score 2):

## Possibly it was a reaction caused by the Dark magic he used.

Though why exactly the Dark Lord exploded as he did in the movie isn’t explained in the movie itself, a similar thing happens to Gormlaith Gaunt, and in her case it was caused by the Dark magic she’d used reacted with the Pukwudgie venom on the arrow she was shot with.

> The old witch had indulged in all manner of Dark magic in an attempt to make herself invincible, and these curses now reacted with the Pukwudgie’s venom, causing her to become as solid and as brittle as coal before shattering into a thousand pieces. The Ollivander wand fell to the ground and burst: all that was left of Gormlaith Gaunt was a pile of smoking dust, a broken stick and a charred dragon heartstring. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Ilvermorny School of Witchcraft and Wizardry (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/ilvermorny)*</sup></sub>

This is a known case of a Dark wizard disintegrating upon death. The circumstances are a bit different, since the Dark Lord is killed by a rebounding Killing Curse, not Pukwudgie venom, but Gormlaith’s death seems very similar to how the Dark Lord died in the movie. The Dark Lord also had used a lot of Dark magic to make himself more powerful, including the potion that restored him to a body. He’d used much more Dark magic than most Dark wizards ever had, so it’s entirely possible that a Killing Curse hitting him could cause a different reaction than it normally would.

Answer (score -1):

An in-universe explanation is that while the AKC ordinarily leaves no trace of operation on its victim, other than their addition to the Chicago voting rolls, the same curse when rebounded against its caster can have a very different effect.  In the books, Voldemort's body exploded at the first attempt to kill Harry.

Comment: In the first book, the effects are different because Voldermort has already split his soul, and therefore cannot be killed.  His body is destroyed, but because of the soul splitting he cannot be killed.  As the AKC has never been stopped or blocked before that point, it may have ordinarily just killed him

Comment: No need for the political commentary.